# While Loop in JavaScript, stuck in infinite loop

Tags: javascript

Here is my code. I am currently stuck in an infinite loop. The program must ask the number of bottles collected for each day for 7 times. So the loop should iterate 7 times. I then must display the total bottles and the total payout of each bottles (which is multiplied but .10) at the end.

```
function main() {
    alert("Welcome to the program");
    var totalBottles = 0;
    var todayBottles = 0;
    var totalPayout = 0;
    var keepGoing = "y";
    var counter = 1;
    while (keepGoing == "y")
        getBottles(totalBottles, todayBottles, counter);
    calcPayout(totalPayout, totalBottles);
    printInfo(totalBottles, totalPayout);
    keepGoing = prompt("Do you want to keep going? Enter y for yes");
}

function getBottles(totalBottles, todayBottles, counter) {
    while (counter < 7) {
        todayBottles = prompt("Enter the number of bottles returned for the day");
        totalBottles = (totalBottles + todayBottles);
        counter = (counter + 1);
    }
}

function calcPayout(totalPayout, totalBottles) {
    totalPayout = 0;
    totalPayout = (totalBottles * 0.10);
}

function printInfo(totalBottles, totalPayout) {
    alert("The total number of bottles returned is", totalBottles);
    alert("The total paid out is", totalPayout);
}
//calls main
main();
alert("End of program");
```

Comment: You're missing the `{ }` around the body of the `while` loop in the first function. Learn to use indentation to clarify your code structure.

Comment: This is why proper formatting is extremely important. Please be more attentive.

Comment: I am brand new to programming and i've never even come close to doing things like this, that is why i'm asking for help. I'm not sure what i'm looking for when the validator says my code is right but my program isn't executing.

Comment: Because your code isn't invalid, but if you add proper formatting and indentation, you will very quickly spot your mistake.

Comment: I understand what you're telling me. What i'm trying to convey is that i don't know what i'm doing. This class was thrown in for part of my degree requirements even though i'm a multimedia major. My teacher makes no sense and isn't willing to help. So this is how i know to format to the best of my knowledge. I put this on here so i could try to better understand and hope to pass the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// please try to understand what it's doing and why was your code not printing the correct info.

```
function main() {
    alert("Welcome to the program");

    var totalBottles = 0;
    var todayBottles = 0;
    var totalPayout = 0;
    var keepGoing = "y";
    var counter = 1;

    while (keepGoing == "y") {
        totalBottles = getBottles(totalBottles, todayBottles, counter);
        totalPayout = calcPayout(totalPayout, totalBottles);
        printInfo(totalBottles, totalPayout);
        keepGoing = prompt("Do you want to keep going? Enter y for yes");
    }
}


function getBottles(totalBottles, todayBottles, counter) {
    while (counter < 7) {
        todayBottles = prompt("Enter the number of bottles returned for the day");
        //alert(todayBottles);
        totalBottles += parseInt(todayBottles);
        //alert(totalBottles);
        counter = (counter + 1);
    }
    return totalBottles;
}

function calcPayout(totalPayout, totalBottles) {
    totalPayout = 0;
    totalPayout = (totalBottles * 0.10);
    return totalPayout;
}

function printInfo(totalBottles, totalPayout) {
    alert("The total number of bottles returned is " + totalBottles);
    alert("The total paid out is " + totalPayout);
}

//calls main
main();
alert("End of program");
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm now having a problem returning the values? When i try to put a return in it just breaks the whole thing. How would i let it keep and pass the values so it will calculate in the end?

Comment: Thank you very much Zain. I am a beginner, trying to learn the best I can!

Answer (score 0):

just put { after 
while (keepGoing == "y")
because according to your code your while loop body contains only one line
        getBottles(totalBottles,todayBottles,counter);
so your program is stuck on that line as keepGoing is always True